# react flux actions and store class dependecies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flux, reactjs-flux

As far as I understand [React-Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#content) architecture, `Flux Actions` classes should propagate their events to `Store` classes via `AppDispatcher`.

However, I saw a few examples were `Action` classes are getting data directly from a `Store` class in order to execute some operations...

example:

```
import ... /* a few more imports */
import AppDispatcher from 'AppDispatcher.js';
import SomeStore from 'SomeStore.js';


class SomeActions {

    processItemData(){
        var item = SomeStore.getCurrentItem();
        .
        .
        // do something with the item
        .
        .
        // then data dispatched (anyway) to SomeStore or maybe other Store class
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({...}); 
    }
}
```

As I see it - importing here `SomeStore.js` breaks the `Flux` architecture and the way the data flows in the app.

The question is, is this normal? isn't it bad practice?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a single correct answer to this, but I would definitely look into passing data from the component, which initiates the action and get data from the store within the component instead of importing store within the action, and thereby sticking to the Flux flow: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/30/flux-actions-and-the-dispatcher.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you thought this is incorrect and breaks the concept of uni-directional data flow. The action could process data provided to it by the component, but I don't see why it would need to, or should, require any data or knowledge from the store.

This breaks the principle of [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control), as the action then needs knowledge of the store's custom implementation, instead of simply dispatching an event with data on it - this is the kind of architecture which flux is trying to avoid!